# Issue with primefaces dynamic dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dynamic Dialog with a CommandButton or an OutputLabel inside, using a value that takes time to generate. To avoid loosing time when loading the page, I used the dynamic param of the dialog. Unfortunately, my function is still called and the necessary time to display the page is very long.

```
<p:dialog dynamic="true">
  <h:outputText value="#{myBean.myFunction()}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Using PF Version 11.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Add appendTo="@(body)" to p:dialog, that should help.

```
<p:dialog appendTo="@(body)" dynamic="true">
  <h:outputText value="#{myBean.myFunction()}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

visit: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/core/dialogframework